# Language comparison in template file

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n

My site has 3 languages. ​In my `node--service.tpl.php`, I've put the following:

```
<?php if ($language = 'es'): ?>
  <div class="more"><a href="<?php print $base_url . $node_url ?>">Leer más</a></div>
<?php elseif ($language = 'en'): ?>
  <div class="more"><a href="<?php print $base_url . $node_url ?>">Read more</a></div>
<?php else: ?>
  <div class="more"><a href="<?php print $base_url . $node_url ?>">Leere más</a></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, it only shows me the language `es` even a page `en`, i.e. it only shows me the first div. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node--TYPE.tpl.php` doesn't include the global `$language` variable as you can see in [this document](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7) but you can still use it by bringing the variable into scope, using `global`.

I've updated your code below to show you how to get this working.

```
<?php global $language; ?>
<?php if ($language->language == 'es'): ?>
  <div class="more"><a href="<?php print $base_url . $node_url ?>">Leer más</a></div>
<?php elseif ($language->language == 'en'): ?>
  <div class="more"><a href="<?php print $base_url . $node_url ?>">Read more</a></div>
<?php else: ?>
  <div class="more"><a href="<?php print $base_url . $node_url ?>">Leere más</a></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Scott thanks for answering. I did what you told me, but I still have the same problem

Comment: I'm sorry my error. if ($language = 'es'): assigns the value 'es' to the variable $language. if ($language == 'es'): for logical comparison. Thanks for all.